# D3 zoom on reusable charts

Tags: d3.js, charts, zooming, multiline

I have been playing around this fantastic example 
http://bl.ocks.org/bobmonteverde/2070123

but was unable to add zoom function to this. 
I have also changed the version of d3 from v2 to v3. Still cannot 
able to get the zooming work.

Does zooming work for this example?

expecting the zoom behaviour like following link - 
codepen.io/amanda-ubben/pen/eDIsH?editors=001

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement zooming on it. You'll need to define a zoom behavior, and then call it on the root svg of your plot.

You'll also need to define a function that tells your graph what to do when the user zooms in on it. Take a look at [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708) as a reference.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I could able to do your suggested example, but I wanted the zoom to work while xAxis and yAxis changes sticks. Have tried the following code but doesn't help. <br/>
<pre> <code>
    function zoomed() {
 
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(chart.x).orient('bottom');
      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(chart.y).orient('left');
  
 var svg = d3.select('#test1 svg');
      
 svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
 svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
 chart.xAxis = xAxis;
 chart.yAxis = yAxis;
 svg.call(chart);
    }
</code></pre>

Comment: You need to change the `zoomed` function. The one in the example applies the `scale` method to the svg canvas, but you can just as easily move points around and change scales.

Comment: Here's an example that shows how to zoom on one axis: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

Comment: The example(http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) has only xAxis zoom there is no yAxis zoom.

Comment: when I use the code that I commented in 13 mins ago, the xAxis and yAxis zooms but not the graph.